# Building llvmlite requires LLVM 14, got '8.0.0'. Be sure to set LLVM_CONFIG to the right executable path

Tags: python, environment-variables, llvm

I want to build a python wheel for llvmlite, however I get this error:

```
LLVM version... 8.0.0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/default/Coding/chaquopy/server/pypi/packages/llvmlite/build/0.41.1/cp39-cp39-android_21_armeabi_v7a/src/ffi/build.py", line 228, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/default/Coding/chaquopy/server/pypi/packages/llvmlite/build/0.41.1/cp39-cp39-android_21_armeabi_v7a/src/ffi/build.py", line 218, in main
    main_posix('linux', '.so')
  File "/home/default/Coding/chaquopy/server/pypi/packages/llvmlite/build/0.41.1/cp39-cp39-android_21_armeabi_v7a/src/ffi/build.py", line 174, in main_posix
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Building llvmlite requires LLVM 14, got '8.0.0'. Be sure to set LLVM_CONFIG to the right executable path.
Read the documentation at http://llvmlite.pydata.org/ for more information about building llvmlite.
```

I have installed LLVM 14 and have manually pointed LLVM_CONFIG to /usr/bin/llvm-config-14, which should be the right executable. However I still get this error. I tried renaming the config file to llvm-config, like suggested on a similar issue, however it still doesn't work. I checked that /usr/in/llvm-config is a real file, that points to the right executable, i tried setting LLVM_CONFIG right to that executable, however i still get that same error

Comment: maybe you should check source code in `build.py` to see how it works.

Comment: did you check if `/usr/bin/llvm-config-14` is real executable? How did you get `LLVM_CONFIG`? How do you run it ? We can't see your computer, we can't read in your mind - you have to show all details in question (not in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the error. The build tool, chaquopy, relies on an wheel for `chaquopy-llvm`, wich i only had compiled for LLVM 8. Changing the LLVM version in the meta.yaml for the `chaquopy-llvm` and re-building it should solve it